Do we need to clear class to prevent memory leak?
In the following script, this class is used to store a lot of Geojsons object (for google maps api):
    class MapService {
      private layers: Map<string, google.maps.Data> = new Map()

      saveLayer(level: Levels, layer: google.maps.Data) {
        this.layers.set(level, layer)
        return layer
      }
    }
    
    export default MapService

This class is used directly inside a vue3 component:
<script setup>
  const layer = { // Some big object }
  const mapService = new MapService()
  mapService.saveLayer(layer)
</script>

This class is only kept in one place, and used in one route of the product.
I have read a lot about Garbage collection, memory leak ... but not really understand everything.
If i open my layer route (and execute saveLayer), go inside another route on the product and open Google chrome inspector memory tab and take a heap snapshot.
I can see that my MapService still exist and have layers inside.
So, i guess, it's still existing.

Do i need to clear big object before leaving some feature of the product?
For example, doing something like this:
<script setup>
  const layer = { // Some big object }
  const mapService = new MapService()
  mapService.saveLayer(layer)

  onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    mapService.cleanLayer()
  })
</script>


class MapService {
  private layers: Map<string, google.maps.Data> = new Map()
    
  saveLayer(level: Levels, layer: google.maps.Data) {
    this.layers.set(level, layer)
    return layer
  }
  
 cleanLayer() {
   this.layers = null
 }

        
export default MapService

And inside script setup, the mapService variable is attached to the component, so it will automatically throw to garbage collection?

Can you out the code inside onMounted ?

The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This totally depends on data object it stores and the way it's used in the component. If data is linked with other things that aren't destroyed on component unmount, notably DOM, this can create a leak. The stuff from google maps can surely do this as they exist in dom, it needs to be verified this is the case.

@EstusFlask This is more of a general question, rather than a specific one in a single case.
I want to know, what i have to do to clean data, when stored inside a class.

Totally depends on data. If it's plain object with map data then nothing needs to be done. If it's new google.maps.Map(...) that is clearly linked to DOM, it can cause leaks and needs to be cleaned up as soon as it's not needed, but it would not need cleanLayer on unmount too. Basically if you're sure you don't use mapService instance after comp is unmounted like passing it somewhere directly or indirectly, it doesn't affect GC in a bad way. The point of cleanLayer would be to not prevent GC during the lifespan of the comp if this data is not used anymore

@EstusFlask Thanks for the explanation, i understand that it really depends on the object itself.
So, maybe a better question, is, who do i know if something is still there and i doesn't want it. Because i need to know it, before doing something about it.
Like my screenshot in memory tab, if i see it, is it that yes the data is not cleaned and affect the app, or not?

Can't say, it's unknown if GC happened in your case. And it's unknown if a component that uses the instance is still mounted. Did you use GC button to test this?
